# Index being ignored by Oracle

Tags: oracle, index, oracle-11g-r2, performance, explain, query-performance

I have a table for sensor data, simplified it looks like this:

```
DEVICE_ID NUMBER
SENSOR_ID NUMBER
DATA_TIME NUMBER
DATA_VALUE1 NUMBER
```

The table constains billions of rows and is partitioned by week number, DATA_TIME is in Unix time (milliseconds since 1970). I have two indexes on this table, IX1 on (DATA_TIME DESC) and IX2 on (DEVICE_ID,SENSOR_ID,DATA_TIME). IX2 was created yesterday.

My query wants to see the data for one sensor in the current month and goes like this:

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL (12) */
   data_time,
   data_value1
FROM table
WHERE device_id = 1041
  AND sensor_id = 202
  AND data_time BETWEEN 1383304859 *1000 AND 1385464859 *1000
ORDER BY data_time ASC
```

I was surprised to find that the optimizer ignores IX2 and comes up with the following plan:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                              |    65 |  1365 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                         |                              |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (ORDER)                    | :TQ10001                     |    65 |  1365 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,01 | P->S | QC (ORDER) |
|   3 |    SORT ORDER BY                        |                              |    65 |  1365 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     PX RECEIVE                          |                              |    65 |  1365 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX SEND RANGE                      | :TQ10000                     |    65 |  1365 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,00 | P->P | RANGE      |
|   6 |       PX PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR       |                              |    65 |  1365 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |   252 |   256 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|*  7 |        TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| table                        |    65 |  1365 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |   252 |   256 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|*  8 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                | ix1                          |     1 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |   252 |   256 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   7 - filter("DEVICE_ID"=1041 AND "SENSOR_ID"=202)
   8 - access(SYS_OP_DESCEND("DATA_TIME")>=HEXTORAW('38FDD8C8BEA9A4FF')  AND SYS_OP_DESCEND("DATA_TIME")<=HEXTORAW('38FDD8DDFAA9A4FF') )
       filter(SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("DATA_TIME"))>=1383304859000 AND SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("DATA_TIME"))<=1385464859000)

Note
-----
   - automatic DOP: skipped because of IO calibrate statistics are missing
```

The statistics on the table and the indexes are recent. I found some SQL Baselines that were created for this statement and removed them.
And on top of that, the SQL tuning advisor recommended creating an index on (DEVICE_ID,SENSOR_ID,DATA_TIME,DATA_VALUE1).

Comment: What exactly is you question? The plan *does* use an index lookup as far as I can tell (I prefer the text output from `explain plain`)

Comment: The plan is using IX1, why not IX2?

Comment: Because most probably using the `data_time` is more efficient. How many rows would be returned by the condition `device_id = 1041 AND sensor_id = 202`

Comment: histograms?!
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_histo.htm#TGSQL368

Comment: Is the index you want it to use global or local?

Comment: Both indexes are local.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Would be surprised by that, because there are 10.000 distinct combinations of `device_id/sensor_id` and data_time is not that selective if you consider the partitioning.

Comment: The table has one row per hour for each combination of `device_id/sensor_id`.

Comment: According to the plan, Oracle thinks than scanning the local index of that partition will only return 1 row: `INDEX RANGE SCAN | ix1 | 1`

Comment: That's the problem, that date range contains about 100 million rows.

Comment: But why? The statistics contain the correct number of rows for each partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem by dropping and recreating IX1. (The reasoning behind that was to invalidate any cached plan still using it.) The query now returns 420 rows after 11 seconds. If anybody can give me a good theory on what happened I will accept it as a correct answer.